# How To Display XML Responses From a Web Service In a Web Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating a web site where I have used a web service called holidaywebservice. I have used Jquery and Ajax to request and get response from the server. I have also console.log(result) to the console tab of the web browser. Now I want when I request , the response is displayed in the web page (in a table for example)

Then I have tried like below. But , in this case, I have to write responses inside the "let soap" in the code myself according to the request. After that I called createTableAndContent(soap) and it shows all the responses. So , this is not a  possible and practical way.

How can I get and display responses in the web page according to request without write in the code.

Here is the file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="signupForm">

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Country : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" value="UnitedStates" id="country">
                    <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Year : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="year" value="2018"
                                  id="year"> <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Month : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="month" value="06"
                                   id="month"> <br>
                </div>

                <a href="#" id="ghsubmitbtn" class="btn btn-success">Search</a>

                <p id="errorModal"></p> <br>

                <div id="ghapidata" class="clearfix"></div>

            </form>

            <p id="body"></p>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $('#ghsubmitbtn').on('click', function (e) {
                        var country = $('#country').val();
                        var year = $('#year').val();
                        var month = $('#month').val();

                        //console.log(departureDate);

                        var str = '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>' +
                            '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">' +
                            '<SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
                            '<ns1:GetHolidaysForMonth>' +
                            '<ns1:countryCode>' + country + '</ns1:countryCode>' +
                            '<ns1:year>' + year + ' </ns1:year>' +
                            '<ns1:month>' + month + '</ns1:month>' +
                            '</ns1:GetHolidaysForMonth>' +
                            '</SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
                            '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

                        //console.log(departureDate);

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?WSDL',
                            method: 'POST',
                            contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                            data: str,
                            //headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + bat},

                            success: function (data) {

                                console.log(data);

                            }

                        });

                        //Test function
                        createTableAndContent(soap)

                    });

                });

                var createTableAndContent = function (data) {
                    let body = document.getElementById("body")
                    let table = document.createElement('TABLE')
                    let tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')

                    table.border = '1'
                    table.appendChild(tableBody);

                    let heading = ["Country", "HolidayCode", "Descriptor", "HolidayType", "DateType", "BankHoliday", "Date"]

                    //TABLE COLUMNS
                    let tr = document.createElement('TR')
                    tableBody.appendChild(tr)
                    for (i = 0; i < heading.length; i++) {
                        let th = document.createElement('TH')
                        th.width = '75'
                        th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(heading[i]))
                        tr.appendChild(th)
                    }

                    let parser = new DOMParser()

                    let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml")

                    let createTd = function (value) {
                        let td = document.createElement('TD')
                        let textNode = document.createTextNode(value)
                        td.appendChild(textNode)
                        return td
                    }


                    //TABLE ROWS
                    for (i = 0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Holiday').length; i++) {
                        let tr = document.createElement('TR')

                        let country = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Country')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
                        let countryTd = createTd(country)
                        tr.appendChild(countryTd)

                        let holidayCode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('HolidayCode')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
                        let holidayCodeTd = createTd(holidayCode)
                        tr.appendChild(holidayCodeTd)

                        let descriptor = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Descriptor')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
                        let descriptorTd = createTd(country)
                        tr.appendChild(descriptorTd)

                        let holidayType = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('HolidayType')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
                        let holidayTypeTd = createTd(holidayType)
                        tr.appendChild(holidayTypeTd)

                        let dateType = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('DateType')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
                        let dateTypeTd = createTd(country)
                        tr.appendChild(dateTypeTd)

                        let bankHoliday = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('BankHoliday') [i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
                        let bankHolidayTd = createTd(bankHoliday)
                        tr.appendChild(bankHolidayTd)

                        let date = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Date')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
                        let dateTd = createTd(date)
                        tr.appendChild(dateTd)

                        tableBody.appendChild(tr)
                    }

                    body.appendChild(table)
                }


                //Data for testing.
                let soap = `<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
                <soap:Envelope
                    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                    <soap:Body>
                        <GetHolidaysForMonthResponse
                            xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">
                            <GetHolidaysForMonthResult>
                                <Holiday>
                                    <Country>UnitedStates</Country>
                                    <HolidayCode>FLAG-DAY</HolidayCode>
                                    <Descriptor>Flag Day</Descriptor>
                                    <HolidayType>Notable</HolidayType>
                                    <DateType>ObservedActual</DateType>
                                    <BankHoliday>NotRecognized</BankHoliday>
                                    <Date>2018-06-14T00:00:00</Date>
                                </Holiday>
                                <Holiday>
                                    <Country>UnitedStates</Country>
                                    <HolidayCode>FATHERS-DAY</HolidayCode>
                                    <Descriptor>Father's Day</Descriptor>
                                    <HolidayType>Notable</HolidayType>
                                    <DateType>ObservedActual</DateType>
                                    <BankHoliday>NotRecognized</BankHoliday>
                                    <Date>2018-06-17T00:00:00</Date>
                                </Holiday>
                            </GetHolidaysForMonthResult>
                        </GetHolidaysForMonthResponse>
                    </soap:Body>
                </soap:Envelope>`

            </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think asynchrony is the issue - because you're calling `createTableAndContent(soap)` outside of the ajax success function

Comment: @JaromandaX - In this case, I have to write responses inside the "let soap" in the code myself according to the request. So , this is not a possible and practical way.
How can I get and display responses in the web page according to request without write in the code.